# create new database on xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

How can I create new database on xampp on centos 5? When I hot mysql -u root -p in terminal it says no mysql command found. When I go to phpMyAdimn page it do not accepts my username/password. What to do in this situation to create new database? Mysql service of xampp is running because when I run "ps ax | grep mysql" I can see xampp mysql process.

Comment: Maybe run the createDB as a PHP script. PHP is also on command-line.

Comment: @Louis: How to do this? can you tell me in detail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to put this in an answer (for the syntax) and it will look like this (in some file called "createDB.php")

You can run it with command-line "php createDB.php", or you can use your browser to set the adress "createDB.php" in your localhost, when you copy your file in the opt/lampp/htdocs folder.

I did not test it but it should work.

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","louis","abc123");
if (mysql_query("CREATE DATABASE my_db",$con))
    {
    echo "Database created";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Symptom: Create new database: No Privileges

Worked for me in "standard" xampp on linux after running /opt/lampp/lampp security:

To add a new database log in to phpmyadmin as user "root" with password as defined for user "pma".

Answer (score 0):

As you have indicate mysql process is running.
So, try

```
locate mysql
which mysql
whereis mysql
```

It could be your login session does not include the actual path to mysql client program.